# ASP.NET Core with - Refresh UI with SignalR when certain changes are made to the DB

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, signalr

I have a notification panel which, by itself, holds notifications relevant to the current user. I am struggling to wrap my head around the whole concept of the Hub and client-side scripts executing together. I want to refresh the UI of the User that receives notification using SignalR.

**The hub class**

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

    public NotificationHub(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        base.OnConnectedAsync();
        var user = this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
        // Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, user);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**configuration:**

```
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IUserIdProvider), typeof(MyUserIdProvider));
```

**routes**

```
        app.UseEndpoints(
            endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                    endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationHub");
                });
```

This is the controller which sends notification to the Dogsitter User, here I want to refresh the Dogsitter's notification UI:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendRequestToDogsitter([FromForm]string id, SendNotificationInputModel inputModel)
    {
        var user = await this.userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
        var owner = user.Owners.FirstOrDefault();
        var dogsitter = this.dogsitterService.GetDogsitterByDogsitterId(id);

        await this.ownerService.SendNotification(id, owner, inputModel.Date, inputModel.StartTime, inputModel.EndTime);

        // Refresh the page to reflect changes.
        await this.notificationHubContext.Clients.User(user.UserName).SendAsync("refreshUI");

        // Notify the user who is receiving the notification. (if connected)
        await this.notificationHubContext.Clients.User(owner.User.UserName).SendAsync("sendNotification", dogsitter.User.UserName);

        return this.RedirectToAction("FindDogsitter");
    }
```

And since my notification panel exists in a partial view which is rendered in the Layout page, I put the scritps here in the layout page itself:

```
 <script>
        var notificationConnection;
        openConnection();

        function openConnection() {
            notificationConnection = new signalR.HubConnection("/notificationHub");
            notificationConnection
                .start()
                .catch(() => {
                    alert("Error while establishing connection");
                });
        }

        notificationConnection.on("SendNotification", (user) => {

        });

        friendConnection.on("refreshUI", (user) => {

        });
    </script>
```

**and finally my MyUserIdProvider which I changed following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/august/cutting-edge-social-style-notifications-with-asp-net-core-signalr**

```
public class MyUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

Basically when a user has to notify another user because of some action I want to the server to listen for the function call refreshUI which will refresh the targeted User UI .I really dont know how to begin working with the client-side part. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to refresh the page when a certain message from ```SignalR``` arrives?

Comment: More like after I submit a change to the Database. Just do a quick refresh to the notifications tab. That's what I dont know.

Comment: If you are using SignalR the notification tab should not be refreshed, this is why signalR can be used for. You just add the notification with no need of UI refresh.

Comment: But how can I do it? In my case at least. My notifications have action links, how to add the notifications in the notification panel with their full functionality using only SignalR and client side code.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a service that connects to the signalR, the notification panel as you already have an on the hub, the methods to get all notifications when the client connects and the broadcast methods, for example:

On your hub, when a client connects you should get all notifications:

```cs
public async Task<OperationResult> GetNotificationsAsync(Groups groups)
{
    try
    {
        IList<OutgoingNotification> notifications = await this.NotificationsManager.GetNotificationsForThisClientAsync(groups).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (notifications.Count != 0)
        {
            // Send the notifications

            for (int i = 0; i < notifications.Count; i++)
            {
                await this.BroadcastNotificationToCallerAsync(notifications[i]).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        return OperationResult.Success();
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        throw new ServiceException(ServiceExceptionCode.NoDataProvidedToGetNotifications, Resources.RES_No_Data_Provided_To_Get_Notifications);
    }
}
```

And on the client:

```js
private async getNotifications(groups: ISignalRGroups) {
  await this.hubMessageConnection.invoke("GetNotificationsAsync", groups)
    .then(() => {
      this.onGetNotificationsComplete.emit();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.onError.emit(WidgetStateEnum.getNotificationError);
    });
}
```

Then when you want to send notifications just inject via DI the hub in your manager to send notifications like:

```cs
private IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationsHub> NotificationsHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationsHub>>();
    }
}
```

```cs
public async Task SendNotificationToGroupAsync(OutgoingNotification outcomingNotification)
{
    await this.NotificationsHub.Clients.Group(outcomingNotification.Target).Message(outcomingNotification).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: I will try this one. Thanks a lot.